# Replace attribute using angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am new to angular.

My question is,
Is it possible to replace 'ng-hide' with 'ng-show' if 'ng-if' is satisfied?

I want to hide and show certain div based on the data I receive. Its either 'true' or 'false', if 'false' the div should be hidden, else it should show.

Comment: what's the problem with `ng-if`/`ng-show` itself..?? your question seems unclear

Comment: ... you shouldn't need to. use ng-show or ng-hide if you want the element to always exist but show or hide based on a value, else use ng-if if you want the element to exist or not exist based on a value.

Comment: That is where my problem is.
I have 2 sets of data. Initially i want to hide both of them, and later after a validation, i get to show either one of the 2 data in a div.

Comment: Could you provide JSFiddle or Plunker? It's not easy to figure out what you need to achieve.

Comment: you only need one of the three directives, and a conditional that has the logic you seek. It could be as simple as `ng-if="foobar"` where `foobar` is a property on your scope that you change based on the logic you need.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra):

```
<div ng-show="cond1 && cond2">
    One data set
</div>
<div ng-show="cond1 && !cond2">
    Other data set
</div>
```

Both data sets will be hidden if `cond1 == false`. If `true`, one or the other will show.

---

Or use [De Morgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
<div ng-show="cond1 && cond2">
    One data set
</div>
<div ng-hide="!cond1 || cond2">
    Other data set
</div>
```

Comment: This solution was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear for me what you need to achieve, but maybe it will be useful:

```
function Controller (SomeService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.firstVisible = false;
    vm.secondVisible = false;
    SomeService.getData().then(data) {
        // firstValidation() function returns true if first way of display is matching
        if (firstValidation(data)) {
            vm.firstVisible = true;
        }

        // secondValidation() function returns true if second way of display is matching
        if (secondValidation(data)) {
            vm.secondVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in HTML:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="vm.firstVisible">
        First way of displaying data
    </div>
    <div ng-if="vm.secondVisible">
        Second way of displaying data
    </div>
</div>
```

(Intentionally I don't use `$onInit` or other stuff to do not make things complicated)